# TypeScript typing issue (marginally related to (P)React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

[Edit: I've simplified my original question]

Let's assume I want to define UI components in exactly the following
way (the following lines shall not be changed in any way - any
solution that will change the following lines is frankly not a solution 
I am looking for ... for example just writing `render({ name: 'World' })`
is not an option ... neither is the non-null assertion operator ...neither using currying or a builder pattern or something like a `withDefaultProps` helper function ... etc. ... these are just workarounds (yet easily working) for the actual problem below):

```js
// please do not change anything in this code snippet

type HelloWorldProps = {
  name?: string
}

export default component<HelloWorldProps>({
  displayName: 'HelloWorld',
  defaultProps: { name: 'World' },

  render(props) {
    // the next line shall NOT throw a compile error
    // that props.name might be undefined
    return `HELLO ${props.name.toUpperCase()}`

    // [Edit] Please ignore that the function returns a string
    // and not a virtual element or whatever - this is not important here.
    // My question is about a TypeScript-only problem,
    // not about a React problem.

    // [Edit] As it has been caused some misunderstanding:
    // The type of argument `props` in the render function shall
    // basically be the original component props type plus (&) all
    // properties that are given in `defaultProps` shall be required now.
    // Those optional props that have no default value shall still
    // be optional. If ComponentType is the original type of the component
    // properties and the type of the `defaultProps` is D then
    // the type of the first argument in the render function shall
    // be: ComponentProps & D

     // [Edit] As it seems not to be 100% clear what I am looking for:
     // The problem is mainly because the function "component" depends basically
     // on two types: One is the type of the component props the other is
     // is the type of the default props. AFAIK it's currently only possible in
     // TypeScript to infer either both of them or none of them (or use
     // default types for the type variables - which is not very useful here
     // as the defaults are {}). But I only want to declare ONE type
     // (HelloWorldProps).
     // All workarounds that I know of are either to explictly declare both
     // types or split the single function "component" into two or more
     // functions - then you do not have that problem any more,
     // but then you have to change the syntax and that is exactly
     // what I do NOT want to do (a fact that is the most important
     // part of the  whole question):

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // export default component<HelloWorldProps>('HelloWorld')({
     //   defaultProps: {...},
     //   render(props) {...}
     // })

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // export default component<HelloWorldProps>('HelloWorld')
     //   .defaultProps({...})
     //   .render(props => ...) // `render` is the function component
     //                         // creator is this builder pattern

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // export default component<HelloWorldProps>({
     //   displayName: 'HelloWorld',
     //   render: withDefaultProps(defaultProps, props => { ... })
     // })

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // type HelloWorldProps = {...}
     // const defaultProps: Partial<HelloWorldProps> = {...}
     // export default component<HelloWorldProps, typeof defaultProps>({...})

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // return `HELLO ${props.name!.toUpperCase()}`

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // render(props: HelloWorldProps & typeof defaultProps) {...}   

     // [this is not the solution I am looking for]
     // render({ name = 'HelloWorld' }) {...}
  }
})
```

How exactly do I have to type the function `component` and the type `ComponentConfig` to make
the above code work properly?

```js
function component<...>(config: ComponentConfig<...>): any {
  ...
}
```

Please find a non-working (!) demo here:

» [DEMO](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&jsx=2#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-6BoBl4wbqXT6l+RrqBwd7QVAMGIfoMFQPynRLCsRDrDKryDnw04+s4XJQPgojQGQRwEPgUA1CgVDZiQ+K4OWC5wIWmhECQRCdLwtFsRC1rkFSeANFAoLpOCULQGGH7MfoklQMsI5EGIAAGB4AKIADLmSgUAACQcHJZAKeqVJpgAqmAkBEFEuBkBAqyvL4RmdO6vivEAA)

[Edit] Maybe this just not possible at the moment. I think it should be possible if this feature would be implemented for the TS compiler.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597

Comment: Just checking to be sure - `defaultProps` might *not* contain all props, and then `props` should not have that as a required element, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, `defaultProps` do *not* have to contain all props.

Comment: @Natasha I've created a diagram to better understand your question https://i.imgur.com/n1SNJTv.png. 1 - required P; 2 - required P and D; 3 - not required P and D; 4 - not required P; and 5 - D without an interception with P (does this image make sense?) Which ones do/don't you want as required/not required to render props?

Comment: @Pedro Please move the red square completely to the right - than your diagram is fine.

Comment: @Natasha "move the red square completely to the right" means that 2 is always void. So do you want 1, 3 and 5 as required and 4 as not required?

Comment: Sorry my bad: Move that red square completely to the top-right corner and scratch off that "5" completely.
If the component itself has four properties `1, 2, 3 and 4` where `1 and 2` are required and `3 and 4` are not
required then D shall be a subset of `3 and 4`.

Comment: @Natasha, as far as I know Typescript (I spent last day thinking in your problem), I think it's not possible to achieve what you want with these conditions.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for your feedback. Maybe you could read the following github issue and tell use your opinion whether this is not possible due to the missing feature that has been requested there:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597
If you agree that this is the reason that my problem as described above is currently not solvable then please open a new answer that says that what I want is currently NOT POSSIBLE in TS the way I exactly want it and link to the above mentioned github issue as explanation.  TYVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days discusses and researches, it's not possible to solve your problem given your restrictions.

As you point in your question:

> [Edit] Maybe this just not possible at the moment. I think it should be possible if this feature would be implemented for the TS compiler. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597

TS won't infer generics at the moment of the function/class declaration. The idea of your issue is the same as for [issue 16597](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597):

```
// issue example
class Greeter<T, S> {
    greeting: T;
    constructor(message: T, message2: S) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

}

// your issue
function component<P extends {} = {}>(config: ComponentConfig<P>): any {
  return null
}

// generalizing
const function<SOME_GIVEN_TYPE, TYPE_TO_BE_INFERED?>() {
  // TYPE_TO_BE_INFERED is defined inside de function/class.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason there's a compile error on your code is because, indeed, `props.name` could be undefined.

To fix it you can simply change the type declaration from

```
type GreeterProps = {
  name?: string // the ? after name means name must be undefined OR string
}
```

to

```
type GreeterProps = {
  name: string // name must be a string
}
```

#### What if you really want `props.name` to be able to be left undefined?

You could just change the logic inside `render`, an example would be:

```
render(props) {
  if (this.props.name === undefined) return 'You don\'t have a name =/';
  return 'HELLO ' + props.name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Why you would need to do that?

The answer is very simple, if `props.name` can be `undefined` you'd just call `.toUpperCase` on `undefined`. Test on your console what happens if you do (PS.: On a real app the result would be even messier).

#### Further notes

By the way, on a typical TypeScript + React App you'd declare default props using

```
  public static defaultProps = {
    ...
  };
```

instead of the approach you've used.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your answer. Maybe my question was a bit misleading: The type definition of "GreeterProps" is perfectly fine as is (that "Greeter" component shall have an optional (!) "name" property). Also that "component" function itself will make sure that if you define a default property for "name"  in the "defaultProps" configuration, that "props.name" inside of the "render" function will NEVER be undefined. But of course the TypeScript compiler does not know this and thinks that "props.name" inside of the "render" function may be undefined.

Comment: The real problem is that my type definition of "ComponentConfig" is just wrong, the type of argument "props" of function "render" MUST NOT BE "P" but more like "P with those formerly optional properties made madotary that are configured in defaultProps".

Comment: BTW: defaultProps will soon be deprecated for function components in React (not for class-based components, of course, because you really need them there). See https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/107

Comment: Do you have a repository or gist containing the code where the issue happens on a real application? Or must the problem be focused on the demo you've provided?

Comment: Of course my "real application" is not a "Hello world" program ;-) ... But providing a full repository would not make things easier, as the problem is exactly the same as in that more or less simple Hello World demo. I've linked a second demo in the question above - maybe that helps to understand my problem a bit better.

Comment: @Natasha You wrote _"...that "props.name" inside of the "render" function will NEVER be undefined..."_. False, you can set `name={undefined}` (or more easily `name={props.somethingWhichMightBeUndefined}`) when using that component. Ergo TS is right here complaining that it might be. If you're sure (you shouldn't) then use `!`. For these cases soon you'll be able to write `props.value?.toUpperCase()` (or `props.value?.toUpperCase() ?? "No name"`, for example).

Comment: @Adriano Thanks for your comment. But I was right when saying "will NEVER be undfined" as the library will take care of that. Of course undefined can be passed in but the library/component function will make sure that it will be replaced automatically by the default prop value before that `render` function is called. That's why it is called `defaultProps`, isn't it?

Comment: @Natasha from React point of view, yes. However TS knows nothing about React implementation and it rightly complains. From TS point of view React MAY even implement it as `props = { ...defaultProps, ...props }`

Comment: @Adriano Like written somewhere above, this is not a React problem, this is a Typescript-only problem ... that's why in my code snippet above there's no JSX and no React imports. If you change the syntax to `export default component<HelloWorldProps>('HelloWorld')({ defaultProps,  render })` typing in TS is working exactly as I want it to work (but I do not like that syntax) .... and the question is whether this is also somehow possible with exactly the syntax as in the above code snippet above (I spend 75% of my credits just because I hoped someone maybe knows some cool TS tricks to fix this).

Comment: Again: it's NOT a TS problem, it entirely depends on how `component<T>()` overloads are typed. Are you free to change how `component<T>` is typed?

Comment: As long as the above code snippet stays really 100% as-is, every solution is very welcome - but this is actually the problem, that this snippet directly shall not be changed at all. I've added a list of workarounds to the code snippet above - none of those workarounds is a solution that I am looking for.

Comment: Interesting problem then, I can't see how to type it correctly without changing the signature (unfortunately with `component<P, D>(config: Config<P, D>)` TS can't automatically infer the type of `D` for `defaultProps`). Let's see if someone can come to a nice solution here!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that what you're looking for is something like this:

```
type HelloWorldProps = {
  name?: string
}

export default function HelloWorld({ name = "World"}: HelloWorldProps) {
    return <>HELLO {name.toUpperCase()}</>
}
```

The main issue you were likely having is that `string` isn't a valid `ReactElement`. Components need to return a `ReactElement`. We wrap the string in a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), which is a `ReactElement`, and return it. Typescript will infer the correct type for the function.

Comment: Thanks Arion for your answer. After I'ver read your answer I have add an additional hint to my question above that the problem is only a TypeScript problem and not a React problem.

Comment: In your example there will not be a "name could be undefined" compile error because of that "{ name = "World" }" default value thing. But in my question above I have explicitly mentioned that this is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution solve your problem?

[DEMO](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&jsx=2#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQAoEsDGBrA8tcSD2A7AQwBsEAnXaAZwB4AVAPlAF5FU16AaUAbwCgQoIUIDaAaVBJ8oNLEi4AZqDoBdALQB%20AFzLQsAB7hY%20ACZVQAJVgpcZEzTHc64lUw2h8sAG6wyoHWICYAC%20IrLySqoMfEEQMPAAwrgAttAExuBJ%20ApIAOY0CHqGxma8wUys-IJCJkhU0MSEkAByhMmwOlTgZFK5nLE1sAqEAK7E4OSUVNps6Fg4BCST1AUM3AOgZCW%20ABTQFNQ6hcAAVBAAFnWS5lQjW8SQoADuFPi5oCfAAJQ6hPiQsWCMRip1Agjol3MyTy53AoAARvBEeAjGRuPCRnCAJKgEy4Dy4OFofC4J6gc6kiD4mz4HD4EawAB0zMZfCgcFASVS6VpWRy%20UKBiMpnMPGC3AAIkVhaVkHNsHgiKQDrQEAwKrw%20DU6g0mq12p1ur1%20oNhmMJiqZhL1kItqZdvspkdQAAyUASn6gP4AoGfGLs%20ByzAKxbKqb0DVBria4SgcSSaThRTKdQzOjSkrmKw2OwOJwuNweby%20fygQKhJORVz%20%20LKMh-KgKWzJMRyKgAQSoVgAjiMkFt7IwWDG44UpDI5MnVJodM4ECoANx8IF8KSo4YoRIpNKeXkEfkFDMispMfja%20qNFptDqgLo9N4m3FDUbjZbTWf1-CN5utyAdruwL2-awPYQbzIqSwqqsaygFqmzbGQewqh%20DZNmQLZtp2PZ9gOqyet6y4gmA4DnPATbEMQpK9KACgjPgKALNIVwAFYjF0Xq4iMyTJI84D4rIsDQBcvQ3EgqTELAfC0fRjGgDY3K7uAh5CpmZTDmKDA7DS-I6FyO4ZHyeR4b8-wjls4B3NI9IUYRsRqPZnLbjycJiQ0sDtLShCyfZPm%20X5NYcgAErAFG4AA6rYxAmG%206lwUQ7QzHevRxdeABMOj0skiJkEuK4GGkZBwiYz7mnJTmKTQwWhRFZBRW%20mlnriOqXvqN4AORVZRNVRW1j7FWar7IbwHjXjobXdSYbWgOKcFwXaxWIY61BfCOQiCCR8CeIYoDEFI8BUOcJDEKAzQYOmJEUGShBlakSASXoZAUGQcFrcRh1wktVCMvF8DQrksIIvAdH9XtJgvfBFlkNIAAGgUAKIADIIxgoAACQ8J933XoyfEAKrQHAZAJIQVCwDsXzBGjGMqlj7SpTjuAAGJIPoIE7KlFPQ3BQLBF8QA)

Basically I've created `ComponentConfig` this way:

```
// Keep the original implementation
type PickOptionalProps<T> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K
}[keyof T]>

// Transform all properties as required
type TransformKeysAsRequired<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
}

interface ComponentConfig<P extends {}> {
  displayName: string,
  // I pick the optional props and transform them as required
  defaultProps?: TransformKeysAsRequired<PickOptionalProps<P>>, 
  // Just transform the props as required
  render(props: TransformKeysAsRequired<P>): any
}
```

Please, tell me if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Thank you, Pedro, for your answer. The link to your demo does not seem to be correct (I cannot see your demo). Nevertheless, it seems that you suggest to make ALL (!) properties of the first argument of the render function to be required. This will make `props.name.toUpperCase()` possible but will allow allow the same for all still optional props .... for example `props.someStringPropWithoutDefaultValue.toUpperCase()` is now fine for the TS compiler, while this will cause some runtime errors later (as this optional prop can still be undefined).

Comment: I've added an additional comment in my code snippet above to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems doable! Take a look at [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&jsx=2#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-evO5jduHAfKXaq0AAYUrkCQFWgH8QHAIDwCksS1hhtURlFCAoLSGa1bROVdHSPUB23lPQDECERjFRGCrRGLCCh6EQFmoWAZEgVB0wAOWQbBZAUJQoMKFcTR1PhDnCBYgz6eQa0ndw+A1eQtR1fVqDtVczQ7HxOz4XBTAKVQCj4YjmLIijqNorB6MUQhOMKbjWF4-i1yCWS1EQBSomfPZ8WzUA2HgVBUHgAB3JQHOYUgo0SKoACsKDkNRQGoCgMAwDNoHgfksEgBMlFTWAMAovM2C8nzyGS79EGgICohA2D8NUTDIOg0C4I7BCTUua5kNQvp0NoQI0IGIwfBrch-1gAg+A-LL9Byv8AKkw4ZLkyzhyDaAKHkPlECoVAVlssAclW99P2ygMkpS7Acv9L5QFWo7jpOoEDlAAAJLBnPgUFrhoT1MIKFBsHPORdIIJajFKL9nhCqqA0yr8Btyq6bru+QHubcIxBe7SSAhmhiEMdrVJC9TKNMGi6JIMGXMR7gmP+o0zjY0QvS0vhiAJ5HSqiApDLmPjm07YcojsxMvSGUBUE4UAZEENB0Co8BiiEVxXOCoHYFQRg5lceZCg5-1qWbAA6OHMG6wRQ0YFrFS4rBptm0AAAMLpFAAZS3wFAAASEQTI1rS1aigBVSALHkN9kBkLAa07ZRTcUlZOyAA).

The interesting types:

```js
// Optional meaning 'could be undefined': both { x?: string } and { x: undefined }
type PickOptionalProps<T> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]-?:
      T extends Record<K, T[K]>
        ? undefined extends T[K] ? K : never
        : K
}[keyof T]>;

type DefaultsFor<P> = Partial<PickOptionalProps<P>>;

type WithoutPropsFrom<T, X> = Omit<T, keyof X>;

// Remove ? or undefined props
type WithoutOptional<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined>
}

type MergePropsAndDefaults<P, D extends DefaultsFor<P>> = {    
    // Props not that aren't both optional & in the defaults stay as they are
    [K in keyof WithoutPropsFrom<P, (PickOptionalProps<P> | D)>]: P[K]
} & {
    // Optional props overridden by defaults:
    [K in keyof (PickOptionalProps<P> | D)]-?: WithoutOptional<P>[K] | D[K]
};

type ComponentConfig<
  P extends {},
  D extends DefaultsFor<P> | undefined = {}
> = D extends {}
  ? {
    displayName: string,
    defaultProps: D, 
    render(props: MergePropsAndDefaults<P, D>): any
  } 
  : {
    displayName: string, 
    render(props: P): any
  };

function component<
  P extends {} = {},
  D extends DefaultsFor<P> | undefined = undefined
>(config: ComponentConfig<P, D>): any {
  return null
}
```

This requires that `component` calls take an explicit type for the default props. It does enforce that the type is correct though, and by pulling the default props into a separate object you could pass this as simply `typeof myDefaultProps`.

The merging here covers a few other cases you haven't mentioned. As a minimal example:

```js
type Props = { name?: string, age: number, optional?: number, undef: string | undefined };
type DefaultProps = { name: 'default', undef: 'other-default' };
type ResultingProps = MergePropsAndDefaults<Props, DefaultProps>;

// Gives:
type ResultingProps = {
    age: number; // Required, because it's required in the main props
    optional?: number | undefined; // Not required but no default: stays optional
} & {
    name: string; // Optional prop overridden correctly
    undef: string; // Non-optional but could-be-undefined, overridden correctly
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, for your answer. It seems that in your example just all (!) optional properties are converted to be required in the first argument of the render function and not only those that are configured under `defaultProps`. Please open you demo and comment the `defaultProps: ...` line and you'll see what I mean: `props.name.toUpperCase()` should now throw an compile error again but unfortunately it doesn't...

Comment: Oooh, interesting. It seems that MergePropsAndDefaults works, but the inference of D in the ComponentConfig doesn't. I'll play with it, just a minute.

Comment: Ok, updated @Natasha. I don't think it's possible to ever have TS infer a type for the default props whilst providing an explicit props type, but you can do it by specifying both just once and have everything else inferred from there, and you can enforce that the specified types are correct. In real use you could infer explicitly with `typeof` to avoid duplication. I've updated the demo.

Comment: To test without default props now: remove the default props line, and it'll force you to also remove the generic arg to match, and then work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for your kind help. But like written in the question above I want to use exactly (means 100% exactly) the syntax in the above written code snippet and the question is how can this be done with exact this syntax - or maybe is it even possible to do that in the current TS version. To be more clear I've added a list of all of the known workarounds for my problem in the code snippet above - none of those workarounds is an answer to my question. Like written above the following feature would for example solve my problem - but this feature is currently not available in TS:

Answer (score 0):

A working solution (yet not exactly what I have asked for) would be to use the following syntax

```js
const HelloWorld: Component<HelloWorldProps> = component({ ... })
```

instead of

```js
const HelloWorld = component<HelloWorldProps>({ ... })
```

Here's a little demo:

[DEMO](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&jsx=2#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYHkzDgewHYEMA2MATpmAM4A8AKgHxQC8siS1ANFAN4BQUvUA2gGkocbFCQQQmAGZQqAXQBccqBAAewCNgAmZKACUICTEW0VB7KkPl0A-FGwQAbhCJRlgrgF9+EqbIUaLi5QSFgScgYDIxMzMmAiUQBzdlxsECDQ6ABhTABbMBwtYAoYVQ0tXXDSMjoogAowCLJlGABKBjo0kGCsqFyCouxgXOxpOCTS8s0dPQ4vdgARacq9GFwiDAJS5jQMHAJiGtKaU6juXm04MjB8XBAAOVw8iGV4xOwUnihtCGlcACu+GAR3ItmUi3Y3yIlVcjWarSgADIoIs2sput5gtIAdgEPsxMZBo5hlN1DMqqC9Ix5ksVrNYBstvgdsg9lg8IRmic6DSvDR6t9jGMJsoBoUSSMcONJjAlkF0f18hLiidONCIMAAUQxPUOvQ6NggfgoAB6U1QABWAPiUGAmHEEAgYDtAAtknoyHACvhoK7XBAsVxzVAALThpXE4oiH0QF7DXAEsPhlOp1O9cDQAASEHw+EwAHUTPhtFTzt88C9wVB3skg8LbTm84Xi9oxcqhiUm-mi0QS1TeVAiSrhvULj9rrd7k8XsoAOTdlt97Rz1jfb6-f5AkEI9V8BzPV5QOe9ktz74Lde8GE6OFNGodcfXzXasQAAyzAFEADLflBQAASDh73IAA6SsIFA+0AFUwEgIhslwMgID1Lw3wvbw2i4IA)